# Recycler view changing layout for all list items not for single list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, chat, layout-inflater

I am implementing chat application in android using xmpp.My Chat is working fine but when i am setting layout for sender and receiver in chat then the inflater is changing layout for all existing list item.
Below is the screenshot when user sends "Hi"
[image]

But when receiver sends "hello" then this chat message is comming to left position but it is also taking other messages to left postion and same when sending messages..
Below is the screenshot when user receives "Hello"

[image]

And followed by this when sending "How are you"[image]

I dont where i am wrong

My recycler view sender layout

chat_layout_self.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chatsymbolself">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cltv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hi"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

chat_layout_other.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
    android:gravity="left|bottom"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/chatsymbolother">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cltv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="hi"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

MessageAdapter.java

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private String user="+918439198269@desktop-5ehan36/Android";
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Message> data= Collections.emptyList();
    public MessageAdapter(Context context,List<Message> data){
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        Message message = data.get(position);
        Log.e("MAdapter", "getItemViewType: from "+message.from);
        if (message.from.equals(user)){
            return 0;
        }
        else {
            return 1;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view;
        MyViewHolder holder;
        if(viewType==0){
            Log.e("MAdapter", "onCreateViewHolder: SEFL");
            view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_layout_self,parent,false);

        }
        else{
            Log.e("MAdapter", "onCreateViewHolder: OTHER");
            view=LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.chat_layout_other,parent,false);
        }
        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        final int itemType = getItemViewType(position);

        Message current=data.get(position);
        holder.chat.setText(current.msg);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView chat;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            chat=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cltv);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post the logs? specifically `Log.e("MAdapter", "getItemViewType: from "+message.from);` should provide some insight

Comment: also can you post the code where you handle a new `Message` when it comes in? i.e. how the new object is added to `List<Message> data` and how `MessageAdapter` is notified of the change.

Comment: I think there is nothing with logs...those are just to show username in logcat.. @Mr. Kevin Thomas

Comment: I have the same problem . How did you solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, it because of your layout which have circular layout size. you should change the TextView width to `wrap_content` rather than `match_parent`.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cltv"
        android:background="@drawable/chatsymbolother"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="hi"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="left"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

1. make your viewholder static
2. You don't need to create deep xml layout, if simple textview is enough.